# Как инициализировать переменную подкласса создавая объект суперкласса?

Tags: java, классы, переменные, инициализация

Картина примерно такая:
Конструктор суперкласса `top(String path) { this.path = path }`
Подкласс `middle extends top` содержит переменную `protected boolean res;`
Подкласс `bottom extends middle` содержит методы и локальные переменные, с которыми должен работать объект `new $top();`

Каким образом при создании объекта `top` присвоить переменной `res` значение `true`?

Comment: @Etki постараюсь передать смысл всего этого иллюстрацией: http://cs630726.vk.me/v630726511/921f/o5-KlW4Dmxg.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Каким образом при создании объекта top присвоить переменной res значение true?

Засунуть в конструктор, если это вычисляемое значение, сделать обычное объявление, если это константное значение:

```
class Middle extends Top {

    private boolean res;

    public Middle(String path) {
        super(path);
        res = zvezdy_slozhilis();
    }
}
```

---

```
class Middle extends Top {

    private boolean res = false;

    public Middle(String path) {
        super(path);
    }
}
```

> Подкласс bottom extended middle содержит методы и локальные переменные, с которыми должен работать объект new $top();

Не должен. Класс либо имеет все необходимое содержимое в себе, либо объявляет некоторые методы абстрактными, либо пользуется экземплярами других классов, но **ничего не знает про наследников**.

Comment: тогда каким образом выстроить иерархию вызова метода следующего вида: $file.read.range.floattype(25, 50); где $file - объект класса MyFile, Read - класс, содержащий переменную-флаг, Range - класс содержит метод получения и проверки значения ?

Comment: @KatoteshiFuku я, честно говоря, не очень понимаю иерархию вызовов. Можете подробнее описать задачу (можно отдельным вопросом, если потребуется)?

Comment: Разобрался. Не стоило мне пользоваться наследственностью, она здесь ни к чему, потому как набор переменных каждого класса различен, а наследственность через ключевое слово extended лишь расширяет исходный набор переменных и методов суперкласса.